# Spring MVC - Insert link in email

Tags: email, url, spring-mvc, path

Excuse the newbie question but I am building an web application with Spring MVC. I have built a registration function that sends an email to the user upon successful reg. The email includes a link to confirm the user's email address. This is all working fine but the URL for the link within the email is hardcoded as:

```
"http://localhost:8080/webApp/confirmEmail"
```

My concern is that when I eventually deploy my app the email links will still point to localhost

I've tried getContextPath() but this only returns "/webApp" so not much use as I need the full URL to insert in the email. What's the best way to get round this?

NB - I'm not using a templating tool to build up the email I'm doing this within the controller (e.g.

```
String body = "<html><body>...</body></html>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the url using `getRequestURL()` from `HttpServletRequest`. Once you have the `URL`  then get the serverURL(protocol, dns and port number, if any) and use it while building the email content.

Comment: Thanks Niranjan. I had already played around with getRequestURL(). This returns     http://localhost:8080/webApp/registerSubmit.html and I was thinking of splitting this string to get     http://localhost:8080/webApp/ and then appending the "confirmEmail". Is this an alternative? I'm guessing not completely safe if/when I change the name of the controller method. 

With regards to serverURL - could you provide more info? I dont understand the connection between the     getRequestURL() and serverURL.

Comment: @SimonTilbury `getRequestURL()` returns the URL with which the end user is accessing  your current requested resource(Page, Servlet. etc). This way you dont have to hardcode the `hostname` while building the `confirmEmail` URL. Btw, you can provide the path `/confirmEmail` in `@RequestMapping` of the corresponding method.

Comment: many thanks. got it working now. seems like a bit of a hack but got it working